# Ender 3 v2 layer skips

Tags: creality-ender-3, extruder, extrusion, underextrusion, direct-drive

I am having some issues with my printer skipping/not extruding random layers of my prints. It happens a few layers in and sometimes doesn't even affect the entire layer. I have tried switching from Cura to PrusaSlicer but the problem persists. My printer is an Ender 3 v2 with dual Z-axis screws, a Micro Swiss all-metal hotend, Micro Swiss direct drive extruder, and a firmware update to reach 275 °C.

I am currently using Polymaker PC-ABS in an enclosure but I have had the same problem with Hatchbox PETG.

I have heard that Z Hop could be the issue when using Cura. I have tried turning it off while using Cura but it did not solve the problem. I have not tried turning it off in PrusaSlicer.

PrusaSlicer settings are as follows:

- 270 °C nozzle
- 95 °C bed
- 0.22 mm layer height.
- 75 % flow for bridges with a 110° threshold for bridges
- 0.85 mm retraction @ 30 mm/s
- Lift Z of 0.2 mm
- 3 walls
- 5 top and bottom layers
- 20 % gyroid infill
- cooling off

[image: Fan duct failure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the v4.2.2 mainboard relating to overheating. Continued overheating will eventually result in the extruder controller on the mainboard going bad.

Solution: Mainboard change to version 4.2.7 and raise your unit to create more air flow. You could also add a fan under the printer.